# Character Navigation

Tags: geometry, open-ended

Consider the following grid of streets with roadblocks:

[image: Map]

If you are facing in the direction of the arrow and want to get to the dot, the highlighted path is the shortest:

[image: L]

This traces out an <kbd>L</kbd>.

Let's try another one:

[image: @]

This traces out the symbol <kbd>@</kbd>.

> Design such a grid so that all the digits <kbd>0</kbd> through <kbd>9</kbd> can be displayed in such a way, by choosing a starting intersection and direction, and a finishing intersection. There must be exactly one shortest path between these points, starting in the direction of the arrow. The 'best' grid has the least amount of blocks, because the destruction of natural environments by cities is already a big enough problem.
>
> However, in accordance with @humn's bounty, please do post answers that might win the honorary 'architectural' prize.

Rotating the street grid is permitted when making your character, reflecting is not. U-turns aren't allowed. Your grid is permitted to have columns/rows with varying height/width as long as it still forms a grid.

Comment: How are characters with discontiguous regions   ( " = % ! and the like) supposed to work?  Are U-turns allowed?

Comment: Either way, this sounds way too tedious and seems more like manual labor than a puzzle to enjoy. Just imagine designing x, X, &, *, and then differentiate between `, ",", ".", '...

Comment: Yes, this sounds too ambitious and not much fun. The scope is too great. Maybe tracing all ten digits can be fun, but all 90-something characters on a keyboard? That's a slog. (I think this puzzle is the wrong way round. It could work if the map and some starting and end points were given and they spelled out a message.)

Comment: Rubio's comment does not only apply to discontinuous letters, but also to the many letters that can't be drawn with a single stroke: A, E, F, T and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions everyone, I've made the puzzle only the digits so that it's better.

Comment: How would you make something like a 3?

Comment: @Wen1now https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cNPm.png

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The planning commission’s
present road map for the future (revised)
has 7 streets
with 4 roadblocks
bounding **6** city blocks.

> [image]

Please forgive the gap in **6**
if, as it seems,
**4** and **8** must have gaps anyway
in any configuration where
they have unique shortest paths.

To be sure, the numbers looked better in the previous plan
with 8 streets and 9 city blocks.
 
Worth noting that
**0**, **1**, **5**, **6**, **7**, **8** and **9**
only require the 6 streets and 3 city blocks
on the west side of town.

> [image]

Comment: Unequally spaced streets are alright. Good job!

Comment: Got some new ideas thanks to you, @boboquack. Also haven't  yet given up on a crazy 45-degree-rotated **8**

Comment: Civic Environmental Panel was glad to see another 3 blocks spared, @boboquack, now down to 6 if it passes spec

Comment: Yes, this is good! I think this is the minimum, unless you can do a 2x2 or a 1xN<=5. If no other answers pop up, I'll accept this 19/1 UTC time.

Comment: No hurry to checkmark, @boboquack, better earned by a solution with nicer looking numbers alone. Would even like to see any different approach. Very enjoyable to work on, as this combines open-ended creativity with the classically puzzling challenge of having unique shortest paths.

Comment: Definitely no need to checkmark now, @boboquack, as this solution has been wikified with a bounty set to garner more variety

Comment: I for one prefer the numbers in the 9 block solution.  The 3 in the 6 block solution is not very crisp.  Maybe with some different spacings

Comment: Agreed, @Trenin, the spacings and **3** wound up so funky in order to eliminate shorter routes for **8**, which for me was the worst troublemaker when trying for just 6 city blocks. I'm not satisfied aesthetically either and hope to see other approaches while continuing to ponder it.